# How to get old Spotlight Search View back for Yosemite?

Tags: macos, spotlight, bug, ui, design

I do not like Yosemite's default Spotlight search. 
It is in the middle of screen and I can see very little outputs at once. 
It is so much helpful when it is full screen.

Example of the window which has limited height and central location:
[image]

**How can you change the location be at the top right corner and height of the hits full height?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of today there is no way to move/resize the spotlight window or to rollback to the previous spotlight (as seen on older OSXs)

I would suggest giving a [feedback to Apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html) about this.

Comment: I sent a feedback about this to Apple second time today and put this time the form which I used to the body of my question.

Answer (score 1):

Here my second bug report to Apple

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was also annoyed by the obtrusive, centrally-located spotlight window. My only solution was to move the window into the upper-right hand corner. OSX remembers the window position so it always reopens in the upper-right hand corner for me now. Slightly more palatable then the original position. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You don't need "old spotlight" it still exists - just do a spotlight search and then scroll down to the bottom of the documents list on the left until you get to "Show all in finder" and (Fx: roll on the drums) magically old spotlight's results will appear!